# LinkedList<E> vs ArrayList<E> cost

Tags: java, data-structures, complexity-theory, big-o

I've read quite a few questions here that discuss the cost of using ArrayLists vs LinkedLists in Java.  One of the most useful I've seen thus far is is here: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist).

I want to be sure that I'm correctly understanding.

In my current use case, I have multiple situations where I have objects stored in a List structure.  The number of objects in the list changes for each run, and random access to objects in the list is never required.  Based on this information, I have elected to use LinkedLists with ListIterators to traverse the entire content of the list.

For example, my code may look something like this:

```
for (Object thisObject : theLinkedList) {
    // do something
}
```

If this is a bad choice, please help me understand why.

My current understanding is that traversing the entire list of objects in a LinkedList would incur O(n) cost using the iterative solution.  Since there is no random access to the list (i.e. The need to get item #3, for example), my current understanding is that this would be basically the same as looping over the content of an ArrayList and requesting each element with an index.

Assuming I knew the number of objects to be stored in the list beforehand, my current line of thinking is that it would be better to initialize an ArrayList to the appropriate size and switch to that structure entirely without using a ListIterator.  Is this logic sound?

As always, I greatly appreciate everone's input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration over a `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` should take roughly the same amount of time to complete, since in each case the cost of stepping from one element to the next is a constant.  The `ArrayList` might be a bit better due to locality of reference, though, so it might be worth profiling to see what happens.

If you are guaranteed that there will always be a fixed number of elements, and there won't be insertions and deletions in random locations, then a raw array might be a good choice, since it's extremely fast and well-optimized for this case.

That said, your analysis of why to use `LinkedList` seems sound.  Again, it doesn't hurt to profile the program and see if `ArrayList` would actually be faster for your use case.

Hope this helps!